# What do I need to use the DatePicker class in Wicket 1.4.10?

Tags: java, datepicker, wicket

Im using Netbeans 7.1, Wicket 1.4.10 with Wicket extension 1.4.10.

I want to use the datePicker, but Netbeans are not able to identify DatePicker as a class. I have searched the library and cant find it ither. Do I need to add som aditional libraries to be able to use the datePicker component? And if so, will I need to install it in som way? The extension I use now is just added usng the tools-librarymanager. Is this the correct way/installation?

Comment: Why are you using 1.4.10? It is ancient, contains many bugs and even several security issues. Upgrade to 1.4.20 **NOW**

Comment: How would I do that? Would it be enough if I just adden the 1.4.20 jar files to the library and deleted the older 1.4.10 ones? Would I still be able to add wicket pages directly in Netbeans as now?(rightclick - new-wicket page)

Comment: Ask the maintainers of the Netbeans Wicket plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3586/wicket-1-4-support

Comment: just copied the new jar files into the library, deleted the older one. Seams to work fine now :-)

Answer (score 5):

You should add the wicket-datetime dependency to your project.

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the project is about to be started it's much easier using Apache Maven. Here's a page on [how to create a Wicket archetype](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html). Then, just open it from NetBeans. If still needed add the dependency to `wicket-datetime` as @magomi has explained.

Comment: The project is not that huge, so I gess I could just make a new one and copy the files(java/html pared) from the old project to the new one and install the Hibernate/wicket/date-time from Maven.

Comment: Don't be afraid to try it Bjørn. It's not gonna byte :)

Comment: It was not that streight forward, so I will try to use it in my next project instead. Got a lot of errors when trying to combine the to, so went away from Maven.  Solved the problem anyway, so thanks everybody :-)